# Openstreetmap change housenumber scale and housenumber color

Tags: javascript, colors, zooming, scale, openstreetmap

when displaying a Openstreetmap map for rural area's the scale on which housenumbers are still shown could be larger.
So I'd like to change the scale where the housenumbers are not visible anymore and i'd like to change the housenumber color 
Anyone knows How?

Comment: Are you rendering your own map? if so, which toolchain do you use for that purpose? As an example maybe "OSM carto style + tilemilll".

How do you define rural area?

Comment: I define the tile in the setview as follows:     

var map = L.map('map').setView(centerOfMap), 16);
           L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                "attribution:  '&copy; Myself'}).addTo(map);

the defnition 'rural or not' is done on serverside

Comment: So you need to create your own map tiles that contain the actual OSM background map itself and adapt it to your needs: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles

Comment: You can't change the appearance of existing map tiles, they are just images. If you want to change their style then you have to either [render and serve your own tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) or choose an alternative tile provider instead, for example MapQuest Open.